# How does $m$ change ratio of the areas?

Tags: geometry, functions

In a Cartesian coordinate system (a coordinate unit should be equal to 1 cm), the equation $y = m(x-5) +2$ describes the set of all points that lie on a certain straight line $g$ in the $x$-$y$ plane. The line $g$ intersects the $x$-axis at a point $A$ and the $y$-axis at a point $B$. Further, there is a point $P$ with the coordinates $P (5, 2)$.

A straight line through the origin $O$ and $ P$ splits the resulting triangle $\triangle OAB$
in the partial triangles $\triangle OPB$ and $\triangle OAP$.

For which values of m exists the ratio of the areas $\triangle OPB:\triangle OAP$ and
is also a rational number for these values?
(Here again all given values for $m$ are considered.)

Comment: You might want to specify $m\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment with different values of $m$ in the [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lj7vp9dk9n) and you will very quickly find the answer to your problem.

The Desmos graph was constructed like this. First, find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts of the line $g$ by substutting $x=0$ and $y=0$ into the equation. Then, find the slope of the line $OP$. Then you can solve for the intersection of the two lines to find its $x$ and $y$ coordinate. Finally, find the areas of the two triangles using $A = \frac{1}{2}bh$ and find their ratio.

Bonus question: can you prove the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ in the Desmos graph is always equal to $-\frac{m}{p}$, where $p$ is equal to $\frac{2}{5}$ in your case?

Comment: I understood the point and method but then I could do many tries, it could be endless? How could I solve and get all the m that fit in this problem? Sorry if u don't mind writting me the whole thing or i can send a photo of what i have done but I didn't get all the m. Or what all vaules for m shoud I try?

Comment: Well my intended answer was $m < 0$ and $m$ rational. Since the distance from $(2,5)$ to the $x$ and $y$ axes is rational, and when $m$ is rational the $x$ and $y$ intercepts are rational, then the ratio of the two areas will always be rational.

Comment: I forgot about thinking about rational m but thanks to you i understood it all now, thanks again